# How to store previous clicked item ? Angular or Simple ( Javascript, typescript need only logic)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to store previous data and using.

Example I am clicked on item one, than click on item second ... I want to store previous [ one ] item. Same situation if click on item five and than click on item nine i want to store item five.

```
  }
```

and html:

```
  <div  *ngFor="let data of allData | async; let i = index;" (click)="selectedItem(data, i )">
    <p> {{ data.name }} </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why do u have to do that? Can you not use array methods(push, pop, slice, splice)? I see the data is not fetched but still using async pipe? First OnClick, store item to the array.. next click check if the item previously-stored is available... if so, return that and push new data. This is simple.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this, local variables, sessions, cookies or webDB etc.

**local variable**

```
 counter : number = 0;
 localVariableClick : any[] = [];
 public selectedItem( i : number) {  
    this.localVariableClick.push(this.allData[i]);  
  }

public seeDataHistyory(counter : number) {

  console.log(this.localVariableClick[counter]);
} 

  <div  *ngFor="let data of allData | async; let i = index;" (click)="selectedItem( i )">
    <p> {{ data.name }} </p>
  </div>
```

**sessions**

```
 counter : number = 0;
 public selectedItem( i : number) {  
    localStorage.setItem(`${this.counter}_value`, this.allData[i]);
    this.counter++;
  }

public seeDataHistyory(counter: number) {
  console.log(localStorage.getItem(`${counter}_value`));
}
```

**cookies**

```
 counter : number = 0;
 public selectedItem( i : number) {  
    document.cookie = `cookie_${this.counter}=${JSON.stringfy(this.allData[i])}; expires=Sun, 1 Jan 2023 00:00:00 UTC; path=/`
   this.counter++
  }

public getCookie(cname: string): string {
    let name = cname + "=";
    let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      let c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return ``;
  }

public seeDataHistyory(counter : number) {
  console.log(this.getCookie(`cookie_${counter}`));
}
```